# Compute f1 score on XGBClassifier

Tags: xgboost

I've trained a XGBoost multiclass classifier with 19 classes. I got a 97% of model score but I'm deeply interesting on compute the f1 score. I've tried with sklearn.metrics.f1_score but I got the following error:

`ValueError: feature_names mismatch: ['f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9', 'f10', 'f11', 'f12', 'f13', 'f14', 'f15', 'f16', 'f17'] ['Frobenius Norm', 'Nuclear Norm', 'Infty Norm', 'Neg Infty Norm', 'Neg L1 Norm', 'L1 Norm', 'Neg L2 Norm', 'L2 Norm', 'eig 1', 'eig 2', 'eig 3', 'eig 4', 'eig 5', 'eig 6', 'eig 7', 'eig 8', 'eig 9', 'eig 10'] expected f12, f15, f11, f13, f5, f4, f10, f6, f3, f7, f1, f17, f16, f14, f0, f8, f2, f9 in input data training data did not have the following fields: Neg L1 Norm, L2 Norm, eig 2, eig 5, Neg Infty Norm, eig 7, eig 6, Nuclear Norm, eig 9, L1 Norm, eig 4, eig 10, eig 1, eig 8, Infty Norm, eig 3, Neg L2 Norm, Frobenius Norm`

Where "Frobenius Norm"... are the ds features. Here is the code

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
```

(Data engineering...)

```
xgb_clf = XGBClassifier(max_depth=8, objective='multi:softmax', n_estimators=150, 
                        num_classes=19)
setattr(xgb_clf, 'verbosity', 2)
```

```
xgb_clf.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
```

```
print('f_1 score: ', f1_score(y_true=y_test, y_pred=xgb_clf.predict(X_test), average='weighted'))
```

I want to compute the f1_score.